# How to determine capacitor and resistor values in this battery management system?

Tags: batteries, bms

I am analyzing an integrated circuit (IC) which has features for protection, monitoring and balancing according to its [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76920.pdf?ts=1678426793611&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ76920). I am also analyzing an [open-source project](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS) on github which uses this IC and looking at the schematic seems to be consistent with the datasheet but I have a question.

How do they determine the resistor and capacitor values, given that the manufacturer does not recommend the values? They only offer an application schematic but some values are missing.

Is there something am I missing?

How could I determine those values?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the datasheet, but it's a bit hidden. Under section 7.3 Recommended operating conditions, you'll find "External cell input resistance" along with "External cell input capacitance."

1k ohm is the maximum value for the BQ76920, and 1uF is listed as typical. They give quite a range for possible values, but together they'd form a 160Hz low pass filter, so that would be one thing to think about. Seeing as they're sense inputs, the actual amount of current flowing into the monitor is more or less negligible, so it's probably not really that important what the value is.

If there's a github project that's used those values and had sucess, I'd probably keep them myself as they seem sensible.

Comment: thank you so much! I have checked them out, now I can proceed with the schematic! Best regards

Answer (score 1):

These are listed in **table** **7.3** on **page** **9** of your [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76920.pdf?ts=1678426793611&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ76920). ("Recommended Operating Conditions")

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! as you stated, I have checked those values out, best regards!